# Issue with Wings and Panel Connection - Error while running `sudo wings --debug`

Tags: sudo

I'm facing a problem with the connection between Wings and Panel. When I try to execute the command `sudo wings --debug`, I'm encountering an error. I attempted to address this problem by using the command `killall -9 wings`, but it didn't resolve the issue.

screenshot of the error message:

[image]

I'm aware that a similar question has been asked before, but the suggested solutions haven't worked for me. I've also searched for additional information in the documentation, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

I'm currently using Wings  and Panel  pterodactyl

I would appreciate it if someone could guide me through the steps to resolve this issue. If possible, please provide detailed instructions, as my English proficiency is not perfect.

[image]